# Remove path & extension on URL via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I know this should be easy but it is beating me. After a site move I want to be able to remove the path to a file along with the extension (if any) and query string (if any) and index.php (if any) to leave just the file name. EG:

```
http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/helloworld.html
301 to >> http://www.example.com/helloworld

http://example.com/anotherpath/apage.html
301 to >> http://www.example.com/apage

http://example.com/index.php/blurb/noextension
301 to >> http://www.example.com/noextension

http://www.example.com/longpath/withsome/morefolders/more.html?dkdhghjghjk
301 to >> http://www.example.com/more
```

There are many different paths in the original site (with and without www), but ***if*** the file ends in .html (with the possibility of a query which has to go as well) I just want it redirecting 301 to the domain/filename

But... to make matters more complex, they can't redirect

```
http://www.example.com/category/something
```

This is because the category is part of the new system (it's wordpress).

Thanks for any help with this!

============

UPDATE - having a few issues but almost there! I adjusted the regex you suggested and now to remove the .html as well and query string (if exists) I have this.

```
RewriteRule ^.*/([^/]+)(.*)?\.h.*$ /$1? [L,NC,R=301]
```

However, it keeps redirecting the home page to

```
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.com/_index
```

Which is puzzling me. Is there something in my regex?

Comment: I edited the answer to the new requirements :)

Comment: I think, its better to create new question than edit old one every hour

Comment: Updating only; not re-writing. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Try this. I think it works properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/category/
RewriteRule ^.*/([^/]+)\.html$ /$1? [L,NC,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/category/
RewriteRule ^.*/([^/]+)$ /$1? [L,NC,R]
```

There are two rules because i could not write in single.
First rule for files (.html) and second for directories (without .html). 
Sign ? after $1 removes query

Answer (score 1):

Write in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```